# Checkbox in react functional component causes rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm using gatsby and have a functional component that loops through some data to create radio button group with an onchange event and checked item. When i update the state whole page component rerenders. i though adding memo was meant to stop this but it doesn't seem to work.

here is the code

```
    const BikePage = React.memo(({ data }) => {
      console.log("page data", data)

      const [selectedColor, setColor] = useState(data.bike.color[0])

      const onColorChange = e => {
        setColor(e.target.value)
      }

      return (
<div>
    {data.treatment.price.map((value, index) => {
                          return (
                            <div>
                              <input
                                id={`bike-option-${index}`}
                                name="treatment"
                                type="radio"
                                value={value}
                                checked={selectedColor === value}
                                onChange={e => onColorChange(e)}
                              />
                              <label
                                htmlFor={`treatment-option-${index}`}
                              >
                                {value}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          )
                        })}
      <Link
                      to="/book"
                      state={{
                        bike: `${data.bike.title}-${selectedColor}`,
                      }}
                      className="c-btn"
                    >
                      Book Now
                    </Link>
</div>
      )

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you update the state the component will re-render, that's fundamentally how react works. the memoised `data` prop is coming from outside of the component.

"If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result" [react.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

You're not changing the incoming props though, you're changing the state

Side note: i imagine that on changing this value you probably want to be changing the state of the data on the server through some means also ( REST POST / graphql mutation). Subsequent refetches of this data would re-render this component as well. It depends what you're trying to ultimately achieve.

Comment: yes but isn't react.memo meant to prevent rerender unless that data is different, which it isn't

Comment: I'm updating the state `useState` not the props coming in. on the change event i don't want it to rerender